# how to compare a nsstring to an Nspredicate contains array

Tags: ios

My code is

```
NSArray *arr;
NSString *valueString=tf.text;
if(![valueString isEqualToString:@""])
{
  arr=[valueString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
}

NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:@"Sunilkaushik" forKey:@"firstname"];
[dict setValue:@"kagushik" forKey:@"lastname"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict1 setValue:@"ankurkumar" forKey:@"firstname"];
[dict1 setValue:@"kumar" forKey:@"lastname"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict2 setValue:@"ankurgarg" forKey:@"firstname"];
[dict2 setValue:@"garg" forKey:@"lastname"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict3=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict3 setValue:@"rahulrathi" forKey:@"firstname"];
[dict3 setValue:@"rathi" forKey:@"lastname"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict4=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict4 setValue:@"gautamgangandhan" forKey:@"firstname"];
[dict4 setValue:@"gahandhan" forKey:@"lastname"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict5=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict5 setValue:@"ajay" forKey:@"firstname"];
[dict5 setValue:@"" forKey:@"lastname"];

NSArray *contacts=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict,dict1,dict2,dict3,dict4,dict5, nil];
NSPredicate *pred;


      pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname contains[cd]%@" ,arr];
    contacts = [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate: pred];
```

it crashed on last line.

Comment: Can you share the message from the crash?

Comment: You should create a brand new array and than do `[contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate: pred]`

Comment: The crash come from `NSArray*` use `NSMutableArray` if you want be able to change your array.

Comment: 'Can't look for value ((
    A,
    n
)) in string (Sunilkaushik); value is not a string ' this is the message i am receiving from crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your array have two objects so pass one as per need either

> NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname
>   contains[cd]%@" ,[arr objectAtIndex:0]];

or

> NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname
>   contains[cd]%@" ,[arr objectAtIndex:1]];

**otherwise make two argument for searching in both array in NSPredicte like:**

> NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate **predicateWithFormat:@"firstname
>   contains[cd]%@ || firstname contains[cd]%@" ,[arr
>   objectAtIndex:0],[arr objectAtIndex:1]];**

Comment: but i want both values in arr should be checked in first name key?? and is it possible without any loop?

Comment: @user3202240 check my edited answer and use last statement it is checking in you both array on first name...  i make that statement in bold .. try it